# Backup /home dir when upgrading Linux from USB

Tags: grub2, backup

Is there a way to backup my /home dir via the Grub menu? I cant boot into my machine, and am trying to reinstall Linux from USB.

Comment: I suggest that you boot from a live drive (USB or DVD) made from an Ubuntu iso file. Then you can mount the partition containing `/home` of your internal drive and use something like the following command line: `sudo tar -cvzf /mounted-external-partition/file.tar.gz /mountpoint-containing-internal-home/home`

Comment: Please only backup private files. Settings do not always carry over to a new release, often the case when going from 1 DE to another (Unity->GDM3).

Comment: That's right, @Rinzwind, there will be problems when you switch between desktop environments. But switching between versions (and staying within the same desktop environment can work well including the settings, as described in [this link](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2259682&p=13769850#post13769850) -- of course depending on the tweaks.

Comment: Hopefully OP is reinstalling the same distro / version / Desktop Engine.